# How to hide Android webView page url when any error?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, vimeo-player

I am using webView for playing Vimeo video in my Android App. But when an error occurs then the webView shows the URL of the video which is dangerous for any production app. How to solve this problem. Please help. Below is my current code.

```
    String vimeoVideo = "<html><body><iframe width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://player.vimeo.com/video/163996646?player_id=player\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, WebResourceRequest request) {

            webView.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
            return true;
        }
    });
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadData(vimeoVideo, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a try/catch block around the code you want to catch when it leads to an exception and hide the WebView element.

Like this:

```
String vimeoVideo = "<html><body><iframe width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://player.vimeo.com/video/163996646?player_id=player\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, WebResourceRequest request) {

            webView.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
            return true;
        }
    });

try {

  //  Block of code to try
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadData(vimeoVideo, "text/html", "utf-8");

}

catch(Exception e) {

  //  Block of code to handle errors
  webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  System.out.println("Something went wrong.");
  
}
```